# Counting unique dates in a data set in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

i should be able to figure this out, but I think I have Monday morning fog-brain.

I have a list of data in datetime format. (it's in the 'Current Data'!D2:D column). I want to count it as a date only.  A snippet of the data is below:

```
5/5/2023 15:06:28
5/5/2023 15:05:27
5/5/2023 15:00:05
5/5/2023 14:46:26
5/5/2023 14:17:55
5/5/2023 13:24:16
5/5/2023 12:52:19
5/5/2023 12:37:33
5/5/2023 11:15:53
5/5/2023 11:15:11
5/5/2023 11:09:00
5/5/2023 10:57:37
5/5/2023 10:14:53
5/5/2023 10:12:07
5/4/2023 15:12:04
5/4/2023 15:09:14
5/4/2023 15:08:50
5/4/2023 13:12:16
5/4/2023 11:05:56
5/4/2023 11:05:38
5/4/2023 11:01:11
5/4/2023 10:56:26
5/3/2023 14:41:22
5/3/2023 14:30:30
5/3/2023 14:29:24
5/3/2023 14:29:19
5/3/2023 14:23:57
5/3/2023 14:00:30
5/3/2023 13:43:48
5/3/2023 12:58:17
5/3/2023 12:54:09
5/3/2023 12:53:00
5/3/2023 12:34:32
5/3/2023 12:19:45
5/3/2023 11:07:33
5/3/2023 11:04:27
5/3/2023 11:01:15
5/3/2023 11:01:01
5/3/2023 11:00:16
5/3/2023 10:43:16
5/3/2023 10:28:09
5/3/2023 10:16:10
```

I'm trying to get it to output in two columns.

I wrote this formula `=query(arrayformula(text('Current Data'!D2:D, "YYYY-mmm-dd")), "Select Count(Col1), Col1 where Col1 is not null and Col1> '2020-08-01' group by Col1 order by Col1 Desc")` and got this:

| Count | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 14 | 2023-May-05 |
| 8 | 2023-May-04 |
| 20 | 2023-May-03 |

**The problem is that the Date column is not sortable as date but only as text.** So my dates are not in the correct order from my 'order by' statement (this becomes a problem when my output goes in the incorrect order May-March-April). What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=query({arrayformula(to_date(tocol('Current Data'!D2:D,1)))},"Select Count(Col1), Col1 where Col1>date '2020-08-01' group by Col1 order by Col1 Desc label Count(Col1) ''")
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your elegant solution for eliminating blanks. Works great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
=QUERY(INDEX(TRUNC(A2:A)), 
           "select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1<>0 
            group by Col1 label count(Col1) '' format Col1 'yyyy-MM-dd' ")
```

[image]